# our fb comments plugin integration is not generating any fb activity feed entries..?

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

i'm not extremely involved in all the possibilites of a facebook integration - but the code configurator/params the comments plugins support, there is not very much room for mistakes/customization.

So i'm actually really wondering myself why our comments plugin is not generating any facebook activity?

i can write a new comment on our website just now:

[image: new fb comment]

and afterwards i can check my activity feed and still, the last entry is from march 18.

[image: no new activity]

i can't find anything about that, there is no config param or anything to control this as far as i know or the docu tells me.. and i tought that this is really a thing that we should have out of the box..right?

Comment: No. There should be a checkbox, in the plugin, where the user can decide that they want to post their comment to Facebook too – but it won’t happen automatically.

Comment: strange, even if check this checkbox, i don't see anything on my wall or in my feed...